# Show second tab as default active

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

**I'm trying to display the second tag as default active tab.**

It's called "slide1link" in the following code.
Would you have a suggestion?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $('ul.tabs').each(function () {
              var active, content, links = $(this).find('a');
              active = links.first().addClass('active');
              content = $(active.attr('href'));
              links.not(':first').each(function () {
                  $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
              });
              $(this).find('a').click(function (e) {
                  active.removeClass('active');
                  content.hide();
                  active = $(this);
                  content = $($(this).attr('href'));
                  active.addClass('active');
                  content.show();
                  return false;
              });
          });

<ul class="tabs">
<li class="slide0link"><a href="#ohne-logo">Ohne Logo</a></li>
<li class="slide1link active"><a href="#heissfolienpraegung">Heißfolienprägung</a></li>
<li class="slide2link"><a href="#blindpraegung">Blindprägung</a></li>
<li class="slide3link"><a href="#motivdruck">Motivdruck</a></li>
</ul >
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: What exactly is your requirement? I think you have written too complex code for simple functionality.

Comment: Do you want the "active" class to be on the list item ("li") or the anchor element/link ("a") - your code is contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

Change: `active = links.first().addClass('active');` 
To: `active = links.first().next().addClass('active');`

Comment: Could you provide a live demo so I can actually look into it?

Comment: Try changing your current `<li class="slide1link active"><a href="#heissfolienpraegung">Heißfolienprägung</a></li>` to `<li class="slide1link"><a class="active" href="#heissfolienpraegung">Heißfolienprägung</a></li>`, Because the class active should be on the  `A`

Answer (score 0):

```
//links.first().addClass('active');
```

this will add class *'active'* to first anchor **'a'** element in the **'ul'**, while in the html you have put the *'active'* class on the **'li'**. If you want to add class on 2nd **'li'** then change the code to:

```
links[1].parent().addClass('active');
```

or, if you want to add class on the 2nd **'a'** (for this you need to put class='active' on **'a'** instead of **'li'**):

```
links[1].addClass('active');
```